# How does the code know when to split into a line?

Tags: python, url, python-3.x, download

So I was learning on how to download files from the web using python but got a bit thrown by one part of the code.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib import request

def download_stock_data(csv_url):
    response = request.urlopen(csv_url)
    csv = response.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
    dest_url = r"stock.csv"
    fx = open(dest_url, "w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()
```

I don't quite understand the code in the variable lines. How does it know when to split into a new line on a csv file ?

Comment: it just splits the input data according to the newline character and stores the splitted parts into a list called lines.

Comment: Yes that I know. But what I don't understand is how it just knows when to split the line. The raw file just becomes perfectly lined without me coding anything.

Comment: `response.read()` reads the entire file and stores the content to a variable.splitting is done on the readed content. I don't now what you mean by `when to split` , you the one tells python to split according to `\n`

Comment: `csv_str.split("\\n")` won't do splitting according to the newline character.

Comment: The lines are perfectly split according to the information in the original csv. But we did not put a command saying where in the data to split it accordingly. We just said \n to split. But which code makes python understand how to print it perfectly like it did on the raw csv file that I just watched.

Answer (score 0):

A csv file is essentially just a text file will comma separated data but they also contain new lines (via the newline ascii character).

If there a csv file with a long single comma separated line for line in lines: would only see the single line.

You can open it up in notepad++ or something to see the raw .csv file. Excel will put data seperated by commas in a cell,and data on a new line into a new row.

Answer (score 0):

"\n" is where the instruction to create a new line comes from.

In the code you have presented, you are telling python to split the string you received based upon "\n". So you get a list of strings split into lines.

When you write to fx, you are inserting a newline character onto every line you write by appending "\n". If you didn't do this, then you would just get one very long line.